# Extract sender activity from postfix logs for auditing user

Tags: email, postfix

We have a mail user on our postfix server that was using the company mail to send compromising information to our competitors.

I've been asked to make a report of the actions for that user in the last time.

There are tools like pflogsumm and others that can extract statistic data, but I haven't so far found anything useful to get all the info for a user because the data is in multiple lines.

I'd like to get something like this:

**For the sent mail**

```
11/11/11 00:00:00 infractor@example.com -> user@anothercompany.com
11/11/11 00:00:01 infractor@example.com -> user2@anothercompany2.com
```

**For the received mail**

```
10/10/11 00:00:00 user@anothercompany.com -> infractor@example.com
10/10/11 00:00:01 user2@anothercompany2.com -> infractor@example.com
```

I know I can do a script by myself, but matching the postfix ID for every mail is not something that can be made with a simple grep, and I've a lot of mail history that I have to recheck distributed among different files and so on.

The source log is the standard postfix format, for example this one...

```
Sep 13 16:15:57 server postfix/qmgr[18142]: B35CB5ED3D: from=<infractor@example.com,   size=10755, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 13 16:15:57 server postfix/smtpd[32099]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 13 16:15:57 server postfix/smtp[32420]: 58C3E5EC9C: to=<user@anothercompany.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.4, delays=0.01/0/0/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok, id=32697-04, from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B35CB5ED3D)
Sep 13 16:15:57 server postfix/qmgr[18142]: 58C3E5EC9C: removed
Sep 13 16:15:57 server postfix/smtp[32379]: B35CB5ED3D: to=<user@anothercompany.com>, relay=mail.anothercompany.com[123.123.123.163]:25, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0/0.01/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 77D0EB6C025)
Sep 13 16:15:57 server postfix/qmgr[18142]: B35CB5ED3D: removed
```

Answer (score 6):

Download perl script [maillogconvert.pl](http://download.vikis.lt/doc/awstats/examples/maillogconvert.pl) and execute it as:

```
perl maillogconvert.pl standard < /var/log/mail.log > result.log
```

Usage:

```
perl maillogconvert.pl [standard|vadmin] [year] < logfile > output
```

The first parameter specifies what format the mail logfile is :
  standard - logfile is standard postfix,sendmail,qmail or mdaemon log format
  vadmin   - logfile is qmail log format with vadmin multi-host support

The second parameter specifies what year to timestamp logfile with, if current
year is not the correct one (ie. 2002). Always use 4 digits. If not specified,
current year is used.

If no output is specified, it goes to the console (stdout).

Comment: This is a dead link...

Comment: please try to download it from: http://download.vikis.lt/doc/awstats/examples/maillogconvert.pl or http://www.awstats.org/

Answer (score 3):

I have created a Perl script: https://github.com/brablc/postfix-tools/blob/master/pflogrep

You can use is as grep:

```
pflogrep infractor@example.com /var/log/maillog
```

Or you can feed the output to `pflogsumm` and get nice statistics:

```
pflogrep infractor@example.com /var/log/maillog | pflogsumm
```

Answer (score 2):

Try "maillogconvert.pl" (perl script), which is included in the AWStats (http://www.awstats.org/).

Answer (score 1):

> **For the sent mail**
>
> ```
> 11/11/11 00:00:00 infractor@example.com -> user@anothercompany.com
> 11/11/11 00:00:01 infractor@example.com -> user2@anothercompany2.com
> ```

```
# awk '/from=infractor@example.com/ { print $1, $2, $3, $7, $8 }' /var/log/maillog
```

> **For the received mail**
>
> ```
> 10/10/11 00:00:00 user@anothercompany.com -> infractor@example.com
> 10/10/11 00:00:01 user2@anothercompany2.com -> infractor@example.com
> ```

```
# awk '/infractor@example.com/ { print $1, $2, $3, $7, $8 }' /var/log/maillog
```

Comment: Are you sure it does work? 
For this -> 
    awk '/from=<infractor@example.com>/ { print $1, $2, $3, $7, $8 }' mail
I am getting only this:
   Sep 13 12:57:56 from=<infractor@example.com>, size=9652,

Comment: This answer is outdated. For example it should be `/from=<infractor...`